# Does assigning more nodes to a job on a SLURM server increase available RAM?

Tags: server, ram, slurm

I am working with a program that needs a lot RAM. Currently I am running it on a SLURM cluster. Each node has 125GB RAM. When submitting the job to a single node it eventually fails as it runs out of memory. My rather naive question, as I am new to working on servers, is:

Does assigning more nodes with the command --nodes flag increase available RAM for the submitted job?

For example:
When assigning 10 nodes instead of 1, with the command below, the program fails at the same point as with with one node.

```
 #SBATCH --nodes=10
```

Is there some other way to combine RAM from multiple nodes for a single job?
Any and all advice is welcome!

Comment: I cant say for sure, but there are distribution methods you can assign : https://slurm.schedmd.com/dist_plane.html

It might also come down to the program you're trying to run also if it can be distributed as a regular job..

Comment: `-m, --distribution=
arbitrary|<block|cyclic|plane=<options>[:block|cyclic|fcyclic]>`

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your program, but most likely no.

To use multiple nodes on a Slurm Cluster (or any cluster, for that matter), your program needs to be set up in very specific way, ie. you need inter node communictaion. This is usually done via [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) and the whole program has to be designed around it.

So if your program uses MPI it may be able to split the workload over several nodes. And even that does not guarantee lower memory as that is usually not the goal of such a parallelization.